# Reference /tags?tab=new in the moderator tools privilege description

Tags: feature-request, tags, 10k-tools, privileges-page, new-tags-page

The [moderator tools privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) description references the the list of new tags in the [stats tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats). It would be better to reference the [“new” tab in the tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new), which includes tag wiki excerpts and doesn't have such a small cut-off (the stats tool cut off is ok for most sites but not for SO's pace).